# Diagnostic plots for logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, data-visualization, diagnostic

I want to check for the assumptions of linearity in my logistic regression model, which states that the logit of the probability is a linear combination of predictors. It might be the case though, that I need to transform one or more of the predictors for a better fit. What I am asking for is some tools to visualize the relationship between fitted probabilities and observed probabilities.

Thanks in advance!